# Get DB information into ListView on a fragment

Tags: android, sqlite, android-studio, listview, fragment

the problem I have is that I want to dump the database in a listview but I get an error and I don't know if it's because I'm doing something wrong.

```
public class MisEntradasLocal extends ListFragment{
    private ListView list;
    private SQLiteDatabase db;
    ArrayList <String> entradas;
    private DbHelper dbHelper;

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_mis_entradas_local,container,false);
    list = (ListView) view.findViewById(R.id.lista);
    dbHelper = new DbHelper(getContext());

    entradas = new ArrayList<>();

    ArrayList <String> items = new ArrayList<>();
    SQLiteDatabase db=dbHelper.getReadableDatabase();
    Cursor fila= db.rawQuery("select * from entradas",null);
    if(fila.moveToFirst()){
        do{
            items.add("Entrada: "+fila.getString(1));
        }while (fila.moveToNext());
    }

    ArrayAdapter<String > listadapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(getActivity(),android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,items);

    list.setAdapter(listadapter);

    return view;
}
}
```

The Databse contain an String field which its idEntrada and other string who is nombreEvento.

Comment: The code above works (with or without rows in the table), as such the error must be elsewhere. Please edit your question and include the stack-trace for the error (not just the error line). You may wish to read this [Analyze a stack trace](https://developer.android.com/studio/debug/stacktraces)

Comment: I found the mistake its because i was extending a ListFragment and i need to change it to fragment

Answer (score 0):

I found the problem. It was that i was extending from ListFragment and I change it to a normal fragment.